# Alternative proof that $\pi$ is irrational

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Is the below alternate proof that $ \pi$ is irrational.

$$
\displaystyle{
\pi = 4 - \dfrac 43 + \dfrac 45 -\dfrac 47 + O_n \\
\text{ First assume that pi is rational and is equal to } \dfrac ab \\
\dfrac ab = 4 - \dfrac 43 + \dfrac 45 - \dfrac 47 + O_n \\
\text{ Now, assume } \Gamma (n) = \prod \limits_{c=4}^n 2c+1 \\
So, a. = 4b - \dfrac 43 b + \dfrac 45b - \dfrac 47b + O_n b \\
\Gamma a = 4b\Gamma - \dfrac 43b\Gamma + \dfrac 45 b\Gamma - \dfrac 47 b \Gamma +O_n b \Gamma \\
\text{ LHS is an integer and RHS isn't, this arises due to our wrong assumption that pi is rational, thus, pi is irrational } \blacksquare \\
\text{We can take n sufficiently large to be close enough to pi.}
}$$

What's invalid in this proof here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the fractions in $O_nb\Gamma$ are not integers, it might be that after you add them all up, they converge on a whole number.  For example, $$\frac32-\frac34+\frac38-\frac3{16}-\frac3{32}+\cdots=1$$

Comment: Okay, that's the point to be noted